# Sequences and Series: arithmetic squence based

Tags: sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations

I have this question on sequence and series that i don't think it should be difficult, but I am running into problems.

The question is this:

> The first 10 terms of an arithmetic sequence adds to 250.
>   Find the explicit form t(n) for this arithmetic sequence.
>   All terms t(n) are Natural Numbers.

I was able to get the solution but I had to basically guess the solution because I ended up with one equation with 2 unknowns.

I am hoping that there is a full algebraic way of solving this without having to guess the numbers required to solve it.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let the first term be $a$ and the difference be $d$ we have $$10a+45d=250\\2a+9d=50$$  Now $d$ must be even and less than $6$, leaving only $2$ and $4$.  If you think $0$ is a natural, add that in.  This gives two or three solutions
$$d=4,a=7\\d=2,a=16\\d=0,a=25$$
Diophantine equations often have fewer equations than variables.  You need to make use of the fact that the variables are naturals or integers to get the solution(s).

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for your input here, I set up something similar myself and had to go about it like this, using some number based properties etc. From series equations for arithmetic I got  t(n) = 50 - a, then from arithmetic sequence I got  t(n) = a + 9d, then I set them equal and got : a + 9d = 50 - a, Final equation I analyzed was : 9d = 50 - 2a, and had to look at possible values of d and a. BUT I considered this to be a very non-analytical way to do it. I was wondering if there is a way of doing it in an exact form. When I got my solutions i only got one: a = 7 and d = 4.

Comment: Hi Ross, I did not know that this is of the form of the Diophantine equations.

Comment: Diophantine equations are ones with the variables restricted to naturals or integers.  They can take any form. In this case there are only a few solutions, while if we allowed the variables to be real there would be a continuous set of solutions.  Responding to your first comment, all of my solutions are correct.  If we allowed integers for the variables you could add any multiple of $9$ to $a$ and subtract the same multiple of $2$ from $d$ and get another solution.

Comment: From $2a+9d=50$ the numbers are small enough to find solutions by sight.  If the numbers were larger you could take the equation $\bmod 9,$ find $2a\equiv 5 \bmod 9$ and solve that using the Euclidean algorithm to be more systematic about it.

Comment: Hi Ross, just wanted to say that I don't doubt that your solutions are correct. It just i was hoping that the solutions was essentially unique I guess. I was not expecting it to have multiple solutions. I like your wording Ross when you used the word SYSTEMATIC, that is what I was hoping for, but to also have at an algebraic highschool level, but I saw that this is probably not possible. I like the way you described the modulo arithmetic and Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$S_n=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}2=5(a_1+a_n)=250 \implies a_1+a_n=50$$

and for $a_{i+1}=a_i+d$

$$d=\frac{a_n-a_1}{n-1}=\frac{a_n-a_1}{9}=\frac{50-2a_1}{9}$$

that is

$$50-2a_1\equiv 0 \mod 9 \implies 2a_1-5\equiv 0 \mod 9\implies2a_1=5+k9$$

which gives the solutions

- $a_1=7,16,25$

Comment: Ok, thanks gimusi, i see you took it to the level of modulo arithmetic, i was thinking about this as well, but I wanted to restrict myself to the level of highschool algebra. Modulo stuff is usually introduced in 2nd or 3rd year in either Number Theory, Group Theory or Discrete Math.

Comment: Since, no one was able to figure this out without going beyond highschool level algebra, I am guessing that it most likely can't be done at the highschool level then.

Comment: Hi gimusi, I think you dropped a zero in the number 50 and it became 5 later on in the equations.

Comment: no I didn’t drop it, I’ve computer $50\equiv 5 \mod 9$